# Technical question about a Fourier transform

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I would like to know if there is an explicit expression for the Fourier transform of the following function:
$$f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}e^{-x-ix^2},$$
or to know where I can find some techniques to have some asymptotical expansion of such Fourier transform.

Comment: it's a Fresnel integral

Comment: Thanks. I noticed it, but are there some explicit expression for these integrals?

Comment: well, it's called a Fresnel integral because it cannot be written in terms of elementary functions (very much like the error function)

Comment: Doesn't repeated integration by parts of the Fourier transform integral give an asymptotic expansion?